# How can I join two tables, keeping rows that do not meet the JOIN condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
ticket                      
+----------+--------+
| ticketID | assign |
+----------+--------+
|     1015 | NULL   |
|     1020 | James  |
|     1021 | Nick   |
+----------+--------+

staffinfo
+---------+-------+
| staffID | staff |
+---------+-------+
|       1 | Jane  |
|       2 | James |
|       3 | Nick  |
|       4 | Cole  |
+---------+-------+

SELECT staff,COUNT(*) as count FROM staffinfo,ticket
WHERE ticket.assign = staffinfo.staff
GROUP BY staff

result:
    +-------+-------+
    | staff | count |
    +-------+-------+
    | James |     1 |
    | Nick  |     1 |
    +-------+-------+
```

Works fine, but infact i need  smthing like:

```
+-------+-------+
| staff | count |
+-------+-------+
| James |     1 |
| Nick  |     1 |
| Jane  |     0 |
| Cole  |     0 |
+-------+-------+
```

COUNT doesnt count records that arent in the table, and since i just started learning SQL, i wanna ask if theres a way to count as the above result?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the count. It's a question about how to do joins.

Comment: @JW: I don't think that those tags are very useful. `select`, really?

Comment: This is basic, basic stuff. The kind of thing that's tackled in any book or beginner's guide to MySQL.

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel I added it because the OP wants to retrieve record and on the wiki it states `Select is one of the most often used SQL keywords.` and so I added it. Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: @JW: They seem too low-level to be useful tags.

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel then removed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should be using `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.staff,    COUNT(b.assign) as count 
FROM    staffinfo a
        LEFT JOIN ticket b
            ON b.assign = a.staff
GROUP   BY a.staff
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee4e3/1)

To fully gain knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN`

The `LEFT JOIN` keyword returns all rows from the left table (table_name1), even if there are no matches in the right table (table_name2).

```
SELECT staffinfo.staff, count(ticket.assign)
FROM staffinfo
LEFT JOIN ticket
ON ticket.assign =staffinfo.staff
GROUP BY staffinfo.staff
```

The `LEFT JOIN` keyword returns all the rows from the left table (staffinfo), even if there are no matches in the right table (ticket).